# configure default path for imports

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using angular cli, and want to configure my import paths, like

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

so I don't write

```
import { NgModule } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/core';
```

What's the way to make my own default paths? so I can import my service like this for example

```
 import { MyService } from '@services';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In tsconfig.json, you can configure TypeScript compiler like this:

```
"baseUrl": "./src",
"paths": {
  "@Services/*": [
    "app/services-folder/*" //All services files inside this services-folder
  ]
}
```

Then you can use your services

```
import { MyService } from '@Services/my.service'; //my.service.ts inside services-folder
```

Comment: any chance you know how to do the same for scss?

Comment: @Victor Bredihin I think same, you put all your scss file inside 1 folder. In tsconffig.json, adding 1 more path "@Styles/*":["app/styles-folder/*"] and refer in your component like: @Styles/app.component.scss

Comment: @VictorBredihin Sr, no idea